# Check Boxes selected

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, checkbox

I am having a problem with check boxes in GUI. I have a 5 check boxes and a button called "generate report". What I want to do is when I press "generate report" I want to check which check boxes are selected so that I can "generate report" with the information selected in the check boxes. I know how to check which were selected but if a check box is selected and afterwards deselected before clicking "generate report" I am afraid that the program won't know if it was deselected after it was selected.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MonthReportGUI implements ItemListener
{
 static Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

 JFrame frame = new JFrame("Month Report");
 JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
 JPanel comboPanel = new JPanel();
 JLabel info = new JLabel("Use the check boxes to select the information to include in the month report");
 JCheckBox checkBoxOne = new JCheckBox("Number accomplished");
 JCheckBox checkBoxTwo = new JCheckBox("Number not accomplished");
 JCheckBox checkBoxThree = new JCheckBox("Total Number of Jobs");
 JCheckBox checkBoxFour = new JCheckBox("Month Salary");
 JCheckBox checkBoxFive = new JCheckBox("Average wage per job");

 Boolean boxOneSelected = false;

 static String [] monthList = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
"October", "November", "December"};

 static String [] createYearList()
 {
   String [] yearList = new String[89];
   String year = (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)) + "";
   for(int i = 0; i < 88; i++)
      yearList[i] = (Integer.parseInt(year) + i) + "";
   return(yearList);
 }
 JLabel monthL = new JLabel("Month:");
 JLabel yearL = new JLabel("Year:");
 static JComboBox monthCB = new JComboBox(monthList);
 static JComboBox yearCB = new JComboBox(createYearList());
 JButton generate = new JButton("Generate Report"); // ACTION HAS TO BE ADDED

 Boolean oneSelected = false;
 Boolean twoSelected = false;
 Boolean threeSelected = false;
 Boolean fourSelected = false;
 Boolean fiveSelected = false;

 MonthReportGUI()
 {
   mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,1));
   mainPanel.add(info, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   mainPanel.add(checkBoxOne, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   mainPanel.add(checkBoxTwo, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   mainPanel.add(checkBoxThree, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   mainPanel.add(checkBoxFour, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   mainPanel.add(checkBoxFive, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   mainPanel.add(comboPanel);
   mainPanel.add(generate, BorderLayout.CENTER);

   comboPanel.add(monthL);
   comboPanel.add(monthCB);
   comboPanel.add(yearL);
   comboPanel.add(yearCB);

   checkBoxOne.addItemListener(this);
   checkBoxTwo.addItemListener(this);
   checkBoxThree.addItemListener(this);
   checkBoxFour.addItemListener(this);
   checkBoxFive.addItemListener(this);

   frame.add(mainPanel);
   frame.pack();
   frame.setVisible(true); //set false
  }

  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) //perform action to know which are selected to use for writting report
  {
    Object source = e.getItemSelectable();
    if (source == checkBoxOne) 
    {
      System.out.println(boxOneSelected);
      boxOneSelected = true;
      System.out.println(boxOneSelected);
    }
  }

  public static void main (String agrs[])
  {
    MonthReportGUI monthReport = new MonthReportGUI();
  }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in storing the selection state of a checkbox in a separate boolean field. Instead, when the button is clicked, ask the checkbox if it's selected directly:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        generateReport(checkbox1.isSelected(),
                       checkbox2.isSelected(),
                       checkbox3.isSelected(),
                       checkbox4.isSelected(),
                       checkbox5.isSelected());
    }
});
```

Doing it like you're doing could lead to correct results, but you're duplicating functionality, introducing a new path for bugs, and making it more complex than it should be.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-issue, since you'll be polling the JCheckBox states at the time of the JButton press only in the button's ActionListener code so all of this will be taken care of. That's the key of event-driven programming. The code only occurs due to an event, and so the program state at the time of the event can be ascertained, and your report generated. You'd only run into trouble if you try to get the JCheckBox state on class construction or in some other non-event-driven way.

Edit: as per JB Nizet's post, I didn't see that you were trying to store the state in variables. Not good. Again, write your ActionListener code and poll your JCheckBoxes then. 1+ to JB Nizet.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:

```
boxOneSelected = true;
```

to:

```
boxOneSelected = checkBoxOne.isSelected();
```

There is the issue about whether this check and assignment should be made in the listener, but you do want to ask the checkbox whether it's selected or not as the core part of the solution.